# Perl: Please explain to me the following behaviours of while()

Tags: arrays, perl, while-loop, file-handling

1.Why does `while (<$filehandle>)` iterate through a file seemlessly, but it doesn't iterate through lists or arrays without manipulating the array itself (like using `while ($_ = shift @array){print $_}`?  How does this happen?

2.How is it that `while ($var = @array){print $var}` manages to iterate through the whole array? Shouldn't `$var` just get the number of indices in `@array` and return that value (so creating an infinite loop)?

From my understanding `while()` reads the conditionality of a statement and loops as long as it finds it true. What I find confusing though is its behaviour around filehandles, lists and the such.

Please help me understand more about `while()` as I find this operator very confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start by looking at `while(<$filehandle>)`. This is actually Perl shorthand for this:

```
while (defined($_ = <$filehandle>)) {
    print $_;
}
```

So each time through the loop, you're reading the next line from the file, and if it is not defined, you'll quit out of the loop. If it is defined, you'll continue. As you expect, `while` will loop as long as the condition evaluates to true.

You'll be able to see that by running `perl -MO=Deparse program.pl`. You can also check out the documentation under [Loop Control](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements). The diamond operator is the same thing as the subroutine [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) (it reads the next line from the file).

---

In the case for `while ($_ = shift @array){print $_}`, you will be modifying the array when the condition for the `while` loop is checked. The subroutine [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) removes the first element of the array and returns it. So `$_` will be set correctly, but your array will start losing elements.

---

In the next case, `while ($var = @array){print $var}`, `$var` will be equal to the number of elements in the array. It's because you're using `@array` in a scalar context. This will mostly likely evaluate to true because from [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

> The number 0, the strings '0' and "" , the empty list () , and undef
>   are all false in a boolean context. All other values are true.

Take this one-liner for example:

```
perl -le 'my @array = qw(a b c d e); my $var = @array; print $var'
```

It will print the number `5`, because there are 5 elements in the array. The `while` loop will not execute if you have 0 elements in your array, and it will be stuck in an infinite loop if there are 1 or more elements in it.

Example:

```
### This code will print 5 forever ###
my @array = qw(hi this is a test);
my $var;
while ( $var =  @array ) {
    print "$var\n";
}
```

For your question 2, it sounds like you are getting different results but this does get stuck in a loop for me.

Comment: Additional information: Non-destructive iteration of an array is provided by `for`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Perl, you will have to get comfortable with special cases.

In the first case, what's special is the diamond operator (<>).

Be careful with 2 as it will break on false values, IIRC.